# How to argue that the expectation of the quadratic variation of an integral of brownian motion is finite.

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

I want to show that $B_t^3 - 3tB_t$ is a martingale. I have shown it is a local martingale via its Ito decomposition:

$B_t^3 - 3tB_t = \int_{0}^{t} 3B_t^2 - 3t dB_t$

I want  to argue that since it has finite quadratic variation, it is a martingale. In terms of showing that the expectation of the quadratic variation is finite, I think it might be easiest to show that:

$ \mathbb{E}[\langle \int_{0}^{t} 3B_t^2 - 3t dB_t \rangle] $

$= \mathbb{E}[\int_{0}^{t} (3B_t^2 - 3t)^2 d\langle B_t \rangle] $

$= \mathbb{E}[\int_{0}^{t} (3B_t^2 - 3t)^2 dt]$

is finite.

How can I show this is finite? I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Try Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Thank you! I will have an exam today and this was pretty much my last unsolved problem, I couldn't find a reasonable solution anywhere.